# Unable to integrate odoo ERP using keycloak SSO

Tags: oauth, odoo, keycloak

how can i integrate odoo ERP with keycloak ERP. There is not much info/documentation anywhere.   i tried following setup

[image]

I see following error

[image]

I have tried with several combinations for Auth url and validation url but odoo throws exception as shown in image.

Comment: It's better to paste the complete log as text since seems that the important lines of the error log were cut in your screenshot. Also figure out that I wanna test your URLs in an Odoo install... should I copy that long URLs from your image or close this post to do something else??

Comment: +1. I am trying to do the same thing, got a bit further than you (using the Google Auth, because it also uses OpenID Connect), but am stuck now on missing nonce support. I think an odoo plugin needs to be written for OpenID Connect authentication.  Also Axel is right. You screenshot misses the most important lines from the bottom.

Comment: IMO it is bug in odoo oath2 code.
Odoo should generate nonce and send it to Keycloak.

Comment: Check your "Validation URL" configuration...
It should be:\n

<keycloak base url>/auth/realms/<your realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect

Replace <...> with your environment data.